# Get Position of Gtk.Button?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm a bit stuck in developing an application with mono. So here's my question: Is there a possibility to get the x / y position of a gtk.Button?
My layout is as follow:

> - Window
>
>   - VBox
>
>     - HBox
>
>       - Button

I would like to have the position because I add a menu popup beneath this button. Currently it only shows up direct beneath the mouse cursor.

Thanks for your help ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the x,y position of any object using the 'Allocation' member variable of the object. For example, if the button is called 'button1', than its x position would be at:

```
button1.Allocation.X
```

and its y position would be at:

```
button1.Allocation.y
```

You can find also the width and height that way, as well as many other relevant details, all in the 'Allocation' member.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, I must be blind :D!